# How to not show a comments field if user logged in

Tags: comments

I have a field called 'email' I added to my node comments form. However I don't want this to display to users who are logged in. What's the best way to hide this field for logged in users?

I created a module 'hideemail.module' (and info file) with the following code, and flushed caches multiple times...but it's still not working. Note: I double-checked the form name with Firebug and the field name in the resource content type > comments fields.

From hideemail.module (and yes its enabled):

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hideemail_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if ($form_id == 'comment-form' && $user->uid != 0) {
    $form['field_email']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if ($form_id == 'comment_form' && $user->uid != 0) {
    $form['field_email']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that, see my edits above...but it's still not working. Am I doing this right by creating a module?

Comment: Yes, create a custom module. Use `dpm($form_id);` and `dpm($form);` to inspect your form's structure to make sure you are using the right id and machine name of your field. That function is provided by the devel module.

Comment: I tried that...everything was correct, so I tried just putting your code into my template.php file instead of a module and it worked.

Comment: From your sample code above, it looks like your form id is incorrect. Perhaps replace the hyphen with an underscore.